# find certain text in page source selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am using selenium to build a texting program for a website. At the moment I'm trying to find certain text in a page. This is what I have tried so far.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.blackhempfamily.com/what-are-the-effects-of-cbd")
a = ActionChains(driver)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
if "What is Hemp & CBD?​​" in driver.page_source:
    result = 1
else:
    result = 0
print(result)
```

Every time I run it instead of giving me 1 it gives me 0 but it's clear that the text is in the site in big bold letters.

Comment: The text you have in the webpage source is `What is Hemp &amp; CBD?​​`. So if you change the text in condition you will be able you get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You should try changing the if statement to

```
if "What is Hemp & CBD?​​" in driver.page_source:
    result = 1
else:
    result = 0
```

because `driver.page_source` gets the letters not any symbols

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
matched = driver.execute_script('''
  return !!document.body.innerText.match('What is Hemp & CBD?')
''')
```

note that if you change that to innerHTML.match it will fail. Why? Because the & in HTML will be &(amp;)